# Matrix cross correlation in python

Tags: fft, convolution, python, autocorrelation, correlation

I'm currently performing matrix cross correlation in python using :

```
C = scipy.signal.correlate2d(A,A)
```

where A is a 2D matrix, typically a picture. As you can imagine, it gets very long for large array, such that I'm looking for something faster.

Any hint ?
I also heard about `scipy.signal.fftconvolve`. Despite that it's much more rapid, it rarely give me the same result at the end.

Comment: my incantation is to ask why do you want to form a large rank 1 matrix?

Comment: Could you say what's `A`? Is it a 1D signal? Is a Random Vector Process?

Comment: A is a 2D - matrix. Typically, it can be an picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scipy.signal.correlate2d(A,A)` and `scipy.signal.fftconvolve(A,A[::-1, ::-1])` will give the same result. The second one is much, much faster.